# foreach in yii create command

Tags: php, yii2

Can you include looping in the Yii::$app->db->createcommand, this is in yii2 like the following example:

```
 $data = Yii::$app->db->createCommand('select 
 regional,".

foreach($tests as $test){
 COUNT(if(sah.kode_mk = "'.$test->kmk.'",1 , null)) AS "'.$test->kmk.'"
}

." from table_test 
 group by regional')->queryAll();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set foreach out of CreateCommand and concatenate result in string:

```
$str = '';
foreach($tests as $test){
   $str .= ', COUNT(if(sah.kode_mk = "'.$test->kmk.'",1 , null)) AS "'.$test->kmk.'"';
}

$data = Yii::$app->db->createCommand('select regional".$str." from table_test group by regional')->queryAll();
```